# How did the doctor know the cause of death just by putting his ear on the dead body?

Tags: plot-explanation, rango

In [Rango](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rango_(2011_film)), How did the doctor know the cause of death is drowning just by putting his ear on the dead body?

[image]

> No, this man wasn't shot. He was drowned!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### He could hear the water in the lungs

The Dr appears to also be pushing on the chest of the deceased. This would move any water in the lungs around which the Dr would hear and therefore deduce that he died via drowning.

Answer (score -1):

He might not listen to the body, most likely he tries to feel if the person is still breath.

It is common that you can feel the breath of a person on your own skin better than to feel the pulse.

Comment: **That is not the point.** The point is thatthe doctor knew what killed whatever is that animal.

Comment: @mattiav27 +1 for "whatever is that animal" - its why I went for deceased in my answer